# How to find a child HWND of a child window of a child window (3 levels deep) with Win32 API?

Tags: api, winapi, findwindow, findwindowex

Suppose I've this Window hierarchy for one of the processes:

```
Main Window               (class name: XYZ_Widget_1)
`- Child Window           (class name: XYZ_Widget_0)
  `- Child-Child Window    (class name: XYZ_Renderer)
```

How do I find the HWND of the `Child-Child Window`?

I tried using `FindWindow` Win32 API function on `XYZ_Renderer` class but the `FindWindow` function doesn't find child windows.

Then I tried using `FindWindow` to find `Main Window`, which succeeded, but after that using `FindWindowEx` can only find `Child Window` as `Child-Child Window` is not a child of `Main Window`.

I guess I could go one layer deeper and call FindWindowEx on the `Child Window` once it's found.

But before I do that I figured maybe there is an easy way to find `Child-Child Window`?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You have to call `FindWindowEx()` for each child level that you want to go down, specifying the `HWND` found in the previous level as the parent, eg:

```
HWND hWnd = FindWindow("XYZ_Widget_1", NULL);
if (hWnd != NULL)
{
    hWnd = FindWindowEx(hWnd, NULL, "XYZ_Widget_0", NULL);
    if (hWnd != NULL)
    {
        hWnd = FindWindowEx(hWnd, NULL, "XYZ_Renderer", NULL);
        // and so on... 
    }
}
```

There is no simplier way to do it.  To simplify your code, you could write your own function that accepts a path of class/window names as input, looping through it calling `FindWindow/Ex()` for each leg as needed.

Answer (score 6):

Call [`EnumChildWindows`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633494.aspx) passing the parent window as `hwndParent`. Your window is the window with class name equal to `XYZ_Renderer`.

The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633494.aspx) states that:

> If a child window has created child windows of its own, **EnumChildWindows** enumerates those windows as well.

Comment: But I don't have the `hwndParent` if I want to find `XYZ_Renderer` from the beginning. I first have to find `XYZ_Widget_0` (`Child Window`) window. But before I can find it, I've to find `XYZ_Widget_1` (`Main Window`).

Comment: You just need to obtain the top level window. FindWindow can do that. Or EnumWindows.

Comment: I did obtain the top level window. If I use `EnumChildWindows` on the top level window it does not find the `XYZ_Renderer` because `XYZ_Renderer` is not a child of the top level window. It's a child of `XYZ_Widget_0`... (See my diagram)

Comment: I'm trying the answer below, where I've to use FindWIndowEx twice.

Comment: I think we're not on the same page. I'm sorry, English is not my native language.

Comment: I can easily find the top level window by `FindWindow`. However calling `EnumChildWindows` enumerats only direct child windows of the top level window. It doesn't find the child-child windows. Does that make sense?

Comment: OK, I missed that comment. `EnumChildWindows` walks the children recursively. It will find all children, all their children and so on. I repeat, `EnumChildWindows` finds all children, and not just direct children. Raymond talked about this: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2007/01/16/1478717.aspx

Comment: Oh it does? In my tests it looked like it only walked one layer of child windowses. Let me re-test. Thanks for your patience.

Comment: I somehow can't get the EnumChildWindows enumerate child windows recursively. It only returns the first level of child windows on my machine. I implemented @RemyLebeau solution below and it woks really well. Thanks for your time and patience.

Comment: You must be doing something wrong. The API really does work as advertised. But never mind. You have a solution.

Comment: I can verify that `EnumChildWindows()` does work as advertised, at least on Win7. It really does enumerate immediate child windows and descendant windows. I created a VCL form with a bunch of nested controls on it, then called `EnumChildWindows()` only once with the Form's `Handle` as the parent window. It did recurse through all of the nested controls.

Comment: Windows 10 and i can see that `EnumChildWindows` only returns top level children. I need to add custom recursion into it to make it return all the children. This is very strange behaviour from API.

Comment: @ScienceDiscoverer that's incorrect